# MS Build Configuration not be shown on the Jenkins screen

Tags: jenkins, xamarin, xamarin.ios, continuous-integration

I am trying to introduce continuous integration in the Xamarin.iOS project. I am following the method that is mentioned on the Xamarin website which is given here
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/#Configuring_the_MSBuild_Plugin .
This is the screenshot of what is expected from the process
[image]
The problem is that the http://localhost:8080/configure link does not shows the MS Build configuration part in which I need to put the path of the xbuild which is "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild" .

I have checked the following things on the Mac:

- MS Build has been installed in the jenkins
- Xamarin.iOS has been installed.
- I have restarted jenkins
- I have checked whether the plugin is present in the the location that is mentioned in the application "/Users/username/.jenkins/"

Is there some other way to go about this continuous integration ?
I have used Jenkins_49.zip in order to install it on the Mac

Comment: The link is incorrect. It should be /configureTools, not /configure

Comment: THANKS... A ....LOT..... I wonder why the this image on the bwesite comes from?... If you want write an answer and I can upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Xamarin documentation contains an error there. The correct URL is `/configureTools`, not `/configure`, i. e. the menu item "Global Tool Configuration".

Maybe the link was correct in an earlier version of Jenkins?